# Issue with ViewPager inside SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have created a tabbed control with `SherlockFragmentActivity` and inside one of the `Fragment`, I am trying to use the ViewPager.

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
{

    SherlockFragment faq = new FAQActivity();
    SherlockFragment help = new HelpGuideActivity();    
    SherlockFragment options= new OptionsActivity();
    SherlockFragment user = new UserActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);


            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle("");
            actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.home);

            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            Tab faqTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("FAQ");
            Tab helpTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Instructions");
            Tab optionsTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Options");
            Tab userTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("User");

            faqTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(faq));
            helpTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(help));
            optionsTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(options));
            userTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(user));

            actionBar.addTab(userTab,true);
            actionBar.addTab(faqTab);
            actionBar.addTab(helpTab);
            actionBar.addTab(optionsTab);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }


    public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        Fragment fragment;

        public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    }

}
```

**HelpGuideActivity.java**

```
public class HelpGuideActivity extends SherlockFragment {



    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    InstructionsAdapter adapter =null;
    ImageView iv=null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_guide_activity, null, false);   
        return currentLayout;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    GlobalContent.screenWidth=size.x;
    GlobalContent.screenHeight=size.y;
    viewPager = (ViewPager)currentLayout.findViewById(R.id.instructionPager);
    adapter= new InstructionsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());        
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }



}
```

**InstructionsAdapter.java**

```
public class InstructionsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int[] resources = new int[]{R.drawable.ins_1,R.drawable.ins_2,R.drawable.ins_3,R.drawable.ins_4};
```

ArrayList fragments ;

```
    public InstructionsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        InstructionFragment fr =InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[arg0]);
        return fr;
    }



public InstructionsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragments  = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    InstructionFragment fr0 =InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[0]);
    InstructionFragment fr1 =InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[1]);
    InstructionFragment fr2 =InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[2]);
    InstructionFragment fr3 =InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[3]);
    fragments.add(fr0);
    fragments.add(fr1);
    fragments.add(fr2);
    fragments.add(fr3);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    return fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 4;
}

}
```

**InstructionFragment.java**

```
public class InstructionFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    int resID =-1;
    public static final InstructionFragment newInstance(int resId)
    {
        InstructionFragment sf= new InstructionFragment();
        sf.resID=resId;
        return sf;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RelativeLayout lt = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_fragment, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)lt.findViewById(R.id.img);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID));
        return lt;
    }
}
```

Above are the different classes & implementations I used. Now, if we switch to this help tab then its working fine. but, if I go to other tab then I come back then I am following exception

```
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1091)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1492)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-02 21:32:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, I would like to know how to avoid this exception? How to use ViewPager inside the SherlockFragment? What is the mistake I am making in the code?

Comment: Why are you using an AsyncTask to set the adapter of the view pager in HelpGuideActivity?

Remove the AsyncTask and just put the code where you call the AsyncTask.

Furthermore, that code should be in onActivityCreated and not in the onCreateView method. 

    `@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }` If you have done this, update your code and I will look at this tomorrow

Comment: how can I put the code in onActivityCreated? How to set the UI then?

Comment: Also.. I changed the code from `onCreateView` to `onActivityCreated`.. Even then, same.

Comment: You should set the UI in onCreateView and the rest of the code in onActivityCreated

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo.. I did the same. even then, same issue!!

Comment: this part is just to clean your code. I don't know what is wrong yet. But I have to make sure your code is correct before I know that isn't what is wrong. So can you Edit your code again? Than I will have another look

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo.. I have modified the code based on the changes you have suggested. Please let me know if I need to make any more changes? I am getting exception in this case also.

Comment: Okay at InstructionsAdapter.java remove `getItemPosition()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`. On top put `ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;` Then in the constructor put `fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();` And then put this 4 times in the constructor `fragments.add(InstructionFragment.newInstance(resources[arg0]);` At getItem put this `return fragments.get(pos);`

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo.. No change. Same issue. I tried with the above thing too :(

Comment: Please edit your code every time you do something like this. Can you maybe put your project online, so I can have a look at it?

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo.. Edited the code. Please check again!!

Comment: you can use isAdded( to omit omit No activity error, but probably it's design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16602540/2767703

You need to reinstatiate the fragment.

---

Somebody also did it without the reinstatiating:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875394/2767703

Comment: Thank you.. This has solved mine. You solution has given relief for my 48 hours effort.