# IllegalStateException on fragment replace with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm using 3 fragments in a page, and when I click one of them, the other two replaces with another two. I guess it's not a good practice to use fragments like buttons but it was working for me. I use setCustomAnimations method to animate changes. My problem occurs when I click the button second time before the first animation ends. I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1800)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code which is called when 3rd fragment clicked:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (currentBottomMenuState == BottomMenuStates.DEFAULT) {
    currentBottomMenuState = BottomMenuStates.RADIO;

    fragment1a = Fragment1a.newInstance(this, radioService.isPlaying());
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top);
    ft.replace(bottomMenuContainerResource1, fragment1a);
    if (radioService.isPlaying()) {
        fragment2a = Fragment2a.newInstance(this);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        ft.replace(bottomMenuContainerResource2, fragment2a);
    } else {
        fragment2b = Fragment2b.newInstance(this);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        ft.replace(bottomMenuContainerResource2, fragment2b);
    }
} else {
    currentBottomMenuState = BottomMenuStates.DEFAULT;
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
    ft.replace(bottomMenuContainerResource1, fragment1b);
    fragment2c = Fragment2c.newInstance(this,
            userManager == null || !userManager.isLoggedIn() ? getString(R.string.loginText) : userManager.getUserFullName());
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top);
    ft.replace(bottomMenuContainerResource2, fragment2c);
}

ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

and here is slide_in_bottom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: put code of slide_in_bottom.xml

Comment: Checkout this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929907/causing-a-java-illegalstateexception-error-no-activity-only-when-navigating-to

Comment: I guess in that case there are nested fragments. i have several fragments but they all are in activity. so I don't use getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: ok then change slide_in.xml and slide_out.xml file, Which i am putting here in few mins

Comment: hey @Palak, I checked your answer but there is a problem. I'm using support library, is there any way to use objectAnimator with support library?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of animation files

**slide_in_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationY" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="1280"
    android:valueTo="0" 
    android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

**slide_out_top.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationY" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1280" 
    android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: I'm using support library, is there any way to use objectAnimator with support library?